# How do I Taskkill a PID that keeps changing?

Tags: cmd, pid

I am trying to kill NlaSvc to force domain to reconnect without rebooting or interrupting the network.

I can do this with taskkill /F /IM 8076 (or whatever number) but the PID is always changing.  The process is unfortunately under svchost.exe, I don't want to end this...

How can I restart the NlaSvc without rebooting, disconnecting the adapter, etc... taskkill works, but only if I know the PID ahead of time.

Any ideas?

UPDATE
Thanks for the solution!  I needed to add two %% to get it to work for some reason.
The below is the full bat, elevates uac, then runs what I need.

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%    \OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .


cmd /c FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=3" %%i IN (`tasklist /fi "services eq NlaSvc"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%i&net start NlaSvc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

cmd /c FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=3" %%i IN (`tasklist /fi "services eq NlaSvc"`) DO taskkill /PID %%i

Comment: fixed.  needed two %%, and had to change to cmd /c to add the net start.  Now it works great!